# How can I configure OpenStack authentication for Terraform?

Tags: terraform, openstack, authentication

I want to use some company terraform files. They all rely on authentication to OpenStack which is the resource they're provisioning from. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your proivder stansa,

```
provider "openstack" {
  # stuff
}
```

It should look something like the above. If it has,

- [`auth_url`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs#auth_url) defined, then it also will very likely have `application_credential_name` and `application_credential_secret` defined.
- [`cloud`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs#cloud) defined, then it's looking for your OpenStack `clouds.yaml`. (Note this is distinct from `cloud.cfg`) Your `clouds.yaml`

  - is documented in [OpenStack](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/config/configuration.html)
  - can be exported from Horizons, the web interface,
  - typically resides in `$HOME/.config/openstack`, and applies for the user. But can also be in the local directory, or installed globally in `/etc/openstack`.
- Has neither `auth_url` nor `cloud`, in which case Terraform will try to authenticate with environmental variables which are [documented here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs#cloud)